# When I run `npm run dev` , I get this error

Tags: reactjs, vite

```
C:\Users\samy\Jobs\sahl_project>npm run dev
```

> sahl_project@1.0.0 dev
> vite

```
X [ERROR] Expected string in JSON but found "<<"

../package.json:2:0:
  2 │ <<<<<<< HEAD
    ╵ ~~

failed to load config from C:\Users\samy\Jobs\sahl_project\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
Error: Build failed with 1 error:
../package.json:2:0: ERROR: Expected string in JSON but found "<<"
    at failureErrorWithLog (C:\Users\samy\Jobs\sahl_project\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1649:15)
    at C:\Users\samy\Jobs\sahl_project\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1058:25
    at runOnEndCallbacks (C:\Users\samy\Jobs\sahl_project\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1484:45)
    at buildResponseToResult (C:\Users\samy\Jobs\sahl_project\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1056:7)
    at C:\Users\samy\Jobs\sahl_project\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1085:16
    at responseCallbacks.<computed> (C:\Users\samy\Jobs\sahl_project\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:703:9)
    at handleIncomingPacket (C:\Users\samy\Jobs\sahl_project\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:762:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (C:\Users\samy\Jobs\sahl_project\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:679:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node
```

:internal/streams/readable:324:12)

I tried to delete `package-lock.json` and the `node_modules` folder and do `npm install`, but that does not work.

Comment: It looks like you have an unresolved git merge conflict in package.json.

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky to say where exactly is the problem from your question but you could try some of these ways to solve the problem,

1. Try to check for merge conflicts by using `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U --relative` to list out the files causing the problem.
2. Try running `npm ci` before you run `npm run dev`
3. Try to freshly clone the project in a different location & run `npm i` on the master & then `npm run dev` to see if the problem persists.
4. Check if you're using the right node version `node -v` compatible for your project.

Answer (score 0):

You have git conflicts in your `package.json` file. You should resolve them (and any other git conflicts) before trying to do anything else.

### Note

You can run `git diff --check` to help find offending git files